# Access DoCmd.OpenReport Where condition issue

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access

I'm trying to print a report, like a invoice. But I have an issue with the Cmd.OpenReport Function.

I have a query for that invoice with a parameter.

```
SELECT EMPLEADOS.CODIGO, EMPLEADOS.NOMBRE, PAGOS.Fecha, PAGOS.Descripcion,
       CONCEPTOS.Descripcion, DETALLE_PAGOS.Monto
FROM ((EMPLEADOS INNER JOIN PAGOS ON EMPLEADOS.CODIGO = PAGOS.EmpleadoID)
      INNER JOIN DETALLE_PAGOS ON PAGOS.IDPago = DETALLE_PAGOS.IDPago)
      INNER JOIN CONCEPTOS ON CONCEPTOS.ConceptoID = DETALLE_PAGOS.Concepto
WHERE PAGOS.IDPago = [COD_PAGO];
```

I join this query with a report. When I open the report, I have to type the ID of the invoice.

[image]

That is OK. But I have to print this report with a Form, I have created a Button to print, and the code is

```
Private Sub txtPrint_Click()
If MsgBox("¿Deseas imprimir?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
    //OTHER FUNCTIONS

    DoCmd.OpenReport "ReportePago", acViewPreview, , "[COD_PAGO]=" & IDPago.Value

End If
```

End Sub

IDPago.Value -> I have a hidden TextBox that store the id of invoice.
But when I click on print button again appear the message box

[image]

If I insert the id of the invoice, print the report, but I don't want to insert the id to print. What can I do to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14937954/pass-parameters-to-access-2010-report-from-docmd-openreport: `OpenReport` expects a `WHERE` clause in its "where" parameter, not just the parameter(s).

Comment: Yes, I try to do it.
DoCmd.OpenReport "ReportePago", acViewPreview, , "IDPago=" & IDPago.Value

And delete the where condition of the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `WHERE` clause from the query, include the PAGOS.IDPago column in the resultset, then pass the condition without the table alias in your call to `OpenReport`:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "ReportePago", acViewPreview, , "IDPago=" & IDPago.Value
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm new with this. How include the PAGOS.IDPago in the resultset?

Comment: `SELECT PAGOS.IDPago, EMPLEADOS.CODIGO, EMPLEADOS.NOMBRE, ...`